Can an LED connected to a USB port draw more current than its own requirement?
I did an experiment with a LED. I powered it with a 9V battery(the common rectangular shaped battery). Do not know its exact current rating but on the internet it is 50mA. The LED was working fine.
Next I took a USB cable, removed its one end(USB B Micro side) and attached the same LED to it. I connected the other end to a laptop. The output of laptop USB port is 5v(less than the battery but more amps maybe around 0.5A). Now the led was more brighter and within 3-4 seconds it became very hot. I removed the USB instantly.
Question: What I have heard is current(Amps) does not matter if it is above the requirement(LED in my case) as long as the volts applied is correct. The reason behind this is the component draws only the required current.
Question: If this is the case then why did the LED drew more current(is what I feel) then required?

A PP3 battery is likely to have more internal resistance than the power supply used for a laptop's USB port, especially if the battery is not new.

To the LED should applied to current source not a voltage. Otherwise you will get positive temperature feedback (temperature rise => current rise => temperature rise => ...).

measure the voltage when the LED is connected to the 9 V battery

@Colin No. But these are common 9V batteries.

@jsotola You mean to measure voltage drop?

@Pratham measure voltage across the LED ... also across the battery terminals

"What I have heard is current does not matter if it is above the requirement as long as the volts applied is correct." - So, did you apply the correct voltage? The answer to that question is very likely no ;)

A properly designed circuit will only draw the current it needs when the voltage applied is within specifications.
You have an LED without a series current-limiting resistor that is calculated for the supply voltage and LED characteristics (and other factors) so you don't have a properly designed circuit.
The current specification for the bare LED is not 'what it needs', more of a 'do not exceed', and it's up to you to ensure that current limit is not exceeded.
There are LEDs with built-in resistors etc. that have a rated voltage and will behave as you expected. The one I've linked is designed for 5V operation and will draw just the current it needs provided the applied voltage is around 5V (maximum 6V) and of the correct polarity. It will not do so if you apply 9V or 900V, it will fail. It won't be hurt if you apply lower voltages but it won't be as bright.

You mean varying voltage(9v and 5v)  are different than what the LED requires that is why there is over heating issue?

The voltage a bare LED requires to get a safe current is not very predictable (it varies from LED to LED, varies with color, manufacturer, with temperature and so on) so you virtually always need some additional components (maybe as simple as a resistor) to control the current. The forward voltage a red LED requires to get to the maximum rated current is around 2V at room temperature, so applying 5V will always be too much.

If you are lucky and there is some hidden resistance in your source the LED may survive undamaged (because the actual voltage across the LED is more like 2V) but usually it will overheat and be damaged or destroyed.

For example, applying a CR2025 Lithium cell across an LED will usually be okay, because those coin cells have a lot of internal resistance and the LED current will not be grossly excessive. The cell voltage will drop because of the hidden internal resistor.

You forgot to put resistor in series with the LED. You can't put a 2V or 3V LED to a 5V or 9V voltage or as much as current flows as possible in the circuit, burning up the LED.
So your question approaches the problem from a wrong point of view.
Your LED will pass all the current available until either the LED burns up, or USB overcurrent protection kicks in, or some fuse blows. It only survived because 9V alkaline batteries are weak sources of current if you short circuit them, as they have rather high resistance.
As an analogy, you don't put 24V into a 12V car lamp either, or 240V into a 120V lamp.

9V battery had low amp than required by LED thats why it survived but the USB port even with low voltage as compared to the battery(more volts than required by LED) but more amps began to heat up the LED?

Any non-ideal voltage source has an internal impedance.
You can model them as an ideal voltage in series with that impedance, something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
That impedance will limit the current you are able to draw from the source.
For a 9 V battery, the impedance may be something like 10 Ω to 200 Ω or more, depending on the type, brand and condition of the battery.
The impedance will form a voltage divider with the load, so the voltage at the load will depend on the current drawn. The voltage across an LED will be determined by the diode characteristics of the LED, so let's say for a red LED it's 2 V. The voltage across the impedance will be the ideal source voltage minus the the LED voltage, so we can use that to find the current.
With your 5 V USB source you said it might be able to provide 0.5 A, that makes it's impedance 10 Ω. The current through the LED will then be:
$$
\frac{5V-2V}{10\Omega} = 300 mA
$$
Enough to get your LED good and hot.
For the 9 V let's say it has 140 Ω impedance, that gives you:
$$
\frac{9V-2V}{140\Omega} = 50 mA
$$
So even with a higher voltage source the current can be less if that source has a higher internal impedance.

Electronic components aren't smart. They don't know how much current they should have. It's up to the person designing the circuit, to make sure the current is how it should be.
In a resistor, the current is proportional to the voltage. That's not because it "should" be that way - that's just how it is. We tried it and that's what happened.
In an LED (or any other diode) they are not proportional. The diode is very sensitive to voltage changes - small voltage changes cause big current changes. We can measure it and draw a chart, like this one (second chart on the page) - your LED might not be the same as the one they measured but the chart will have a similar shape. The red LED they tested had almost no current at 1.3 volts; at 1.5 volts it reaches 5mA which is a good amount of light to see that it's on; at 2 volts the current is already up to 40mA which is probably too high, and it only goes up from there.
Why is it this way? Well it just is. I'm sure there is an explanation in quantum physics, but if you're not a quantum physicist then it just is that way and you just have to deal with it.
Since you are designing the circuit it is your job to make the LED's current as high as you want it. 20mA is a good number for those little round LEDs and makes them quite bright. 5mA is a good number if you want it comfortably bright (enough to see in a well lit room) but not too bright. I don't know your LED so maybe 50mA is good for you, as you say - that will be quite bright. Let's assume you do want 50mA. Then it's your job to make sure it will be 50mA.
You could build a "smart" current regulator, with a few transistors, some resistors and a Zener diode, that will balance the current at exactly 50mA. But that's a bit overkill.
What most people do is simply put a resistor in series with the LED, so the resistor voltage and the LED voltage will add up to the battery voltage, when the current is about right.
Using a red LED, 5V USB and 50mA as an example, you can say the LED voltage will be about 2V (according to the chart before; if you have a more accurate chart, use it) which means the resistor voltage needs to be 3V when the current is 50mA. 3V divided by 50mA is 60 ohms and that's the resistor you'd want to use. They don't make 60 ohm resistors, so you'd use the closest one which is 56 ohms. This method doesn't give a precise amount of current, like if you built a current regulator, but it's close enough and all you need is one resistor.
Why does it work with the 9V battery? Well, 9V batteries are actually pretty weak, current-wise. They're better to provide a small amount of current for a long time. The battery voltage would have dropped as the LED voltage rose, until they met somewhere in the middle with a high but not crazy amount of current (maybe 100 to 150mA - you could measure it if you want). The USB port is stronger, able to provide more current, probably at least 2A even if the label says 0.5A.
